# RHEL service works when starting manually, but won't start automatically when enabled for reboot. (main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a)

Tags: services, reboot, systemctl, jboss

I created a linux service to start a shell script when the server (re)starts.
While testing my server I saw that the service is able to start when I do it manually but won't start when I enable it with "systemctl". What is causing this?

My logs:

**systemctl status script.service**

```
 script.service - name
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/scriptname.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2024-03-04 15:39:34 CET; 3min 45s ago
  Process: 1303 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/scriptname.sh (code=exited, status=126)
 Main PID: 1303 (code=exited, status=126)

Mar 04 15:39:34 sar systemd[1]: Started ######.
Mar 04 15:39:34 sar systemd[1]: scriptname.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
Mar 04 15:39:34 sar systemd[1]: Unit scriptname.service entered failed state.
Mar 04 15:39:34 sar systemd[1]: scriptname.service failed.
```

**journalctl -u servicename.service | tail -n 50**

```
-- Reboot --
Mar 04 15:39:34 sar systemd[1]: Started #####.
Mar 04 15:39:34 sar systemd[1]: scriptname.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=126/n/a
Mar 04 15:39:34 sar systemd[1]: Unit scriptname.service entered failed state.
Mar 04 15:39:34 sar systemd[1]: scriptname.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution:**

Making the following changes to the service file fixed my issue:

- Add the `Group`, `Restart` and `WantedBy` line and it should start without issues.
- Change the group ID to that of your own user.

```shell
vi /etc/systemd/system/servicename.service
```

```ini
[Unit]
Description= app description
After=network.target
Wants=network-online.target      #(optional)

[Service]
Type=simple
User=t9s1takuser
Group=208816585
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Generally, `systemd` attempts to run as many units in parallel as possible, and to run units as early as possible. Also the `network.target` has a very fuzzy definition. So, since the only `After=` line is `After=network.target`, it guarantees the service is stopped at system shutdown before network interfaces are shut down, but not much else... so it might be trying to start too early. See `man systemd.special`, particularly the description of `network.target` in there. Also see http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget .

Comment: If your service expects the network to be fully available when the service is started, you might want to replace the `After=network.target` with `Wants=network-online.target`, `After=network-online.target`.